# C++ vector matching

Tags: c++

I'm just messing around with vectors. In the first two loops I'm populating each vector with the number 1 and jumping to the next index and doing the same thing. In my last loop I'm just counting the number of indices that both contain the number 1. Why is the count returning 3 and not 1? The only indices that both contain the number 1 should be zero.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
vector <int> v1;
vector <int> v2;
int N = 20;
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= N; i+=3) {
    v1.push_back(1);
}
for(int i = 0; i <= N; i+=7) {
    v2.push_back(1);
}

for(int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
    if(v1[i] == 1 && v2[i] == 1) count++;
}
cout << count;  // returns 3. But why!? 
}
```

Comment: Because you have `1` allover in your vectors, accessing `v1` beyond an index of `2` is undefined behavior though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has **undefined behavior** because you are accessing them beyond the size. In `v1` there will be 7 items, while in `v2`, there will be 3. But you are accessing both upto index 20. So the output can be *anything*.

To avoid this, you can `resize` your vectors and then assign `1` to specified indexes.

```
v1.resize(N); // keep enough space
v2.resize(N);


for(int i = 0; i < N; i+=3) {
 v1[i]=1;
}
for(int i = 0; i < N; i+=7) {
 v2[i]=1;
}
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
 if(v1[i] == 1 && v2[i] == 1) count++;
}
```

Another problem is your loop conditions are `i<=N`, which should be `i<N`. `vector` has zero based index.

Answer (score 0):

The vector is not an array, that means there are no gaps between the pushed entries.

In the first vector, you have 6 entries, in the second, you have 3 entries, the first 3 entries match, so you get 3.

I would expect that v1[i] and v2[i] would give an error when i becomes more than the number of elements in the vector though.

Comment: `operator[]` doesn't do bounds checking, but there is `v1.at(i)` if you want to have that error caught

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws an exception as `v1` has 7 items after the push_back loop - while `v2` has 3.

you can't access `v1[8]...v1[20]`

Comment: _'You code throws an exception'_ Not necessarily ...

Comment: at least on my machine it always throws an exception